# Play sometimes shutdown with memcached client shutdown

Tags: java, playframework, spymemcached, memcachedb

My production play server sometimes shutdowns without any warning .

The last message in system.out is:

```
     ~ Selection key is not valid.

INFO   | jvm 9    | 2012/02/27 11:01:23 | 11:01:22,654 %0-5p  ~ Shut down memcached client

INFO   | jvm 9    | 2012/02/27 11:01:23 | 11:01:22,657 %0-5p  ~ Shut down channel java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]

INFO   | jvm 9    | 2012/02/27 11:01:23 | 11:01:22,672 %0-5p  ~ Shut down selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl
```

error happens in spymemcached.jar

Why? Any reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Not enough info there to answer. Is there a particular reason you are using a separate cache client as opposed to Play's Cache object?

Comment: i is using Memcached-Java-Client

Comment: Why not use Play's Cache class instead?

Comment: You will need to provide a full stack trace in order to debug this issue. Also, when an exception is thrown in Spymemcached we try to reconnect and will never shutdown the client for you. It's likely that your catching an exception and shutting down the client yourself.